# Grails controller request variable

Tags: grails

In our grails 1.3.x apps we used to do `def user = request.userDefinedInAFilter` and that was not in a controller method but in the body of the class and that worked fine.  Now when upgrading to 2.1.2 that gives this error when trying to create the bean:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.MyController.getRequest() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I can put that in the controller method or in a before block just trying to figure the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is because those methods were previously added to the metaclass, but are now added to the bytecode via AST transformations. If you need that for all methods you can add it to a `beforeInterceptor` and set the field there, or make the call in each method that needs it.

Comment: Thanks. It was few and far between so for now I'm just moving it into the methods where necessary.  It was only one controller where it was required by every method.